# Kibana error: Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. socket hang up

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, networking, kibana, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy elasticsearch and kibana to kubernetes using [this chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts) and getting this error inside the kibana container, therefore ingress returns 503 error and container is never ready.

Error:

```
[2022-11-08T12:30:53.321+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. socket hang up - Local: 10.112.130.148:42748, Remote: 10.96.237.95:9200
```

Ip adress 10.96.237.95 is a valid elasticsearch service address, and port is right.

When i am doing curl to elasticsearch from inside the kibana container, it successfully returns a response.

Am i missing something in my configurations?

**Chart version: 7.17.3**

Values for elasticsearch chart:

```
clusterName: "elasticsearch"
nodeGroup: "master"

createCert: false

roles:
  master: "true"
  data: "true"
  ingest: "true"
  ml: "true"
  transform: "true"
  remote_cluster_client: "true"

protocol: https

replicas: 2

sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144

readinessProbe:
   failureThreshold: 3
   initialDelaySeconds: 90
   periodSeconds: 10
   successThreshold: 1
   timeoutSeconds: 10

imageTag: "7.17.3"

extraEnvs:
- name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: elasticsearch-creds
      key: password
- name: ELASTIC_USERNAME
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: elasticsearch-creds
      key: username

clusterHealthCheckParams: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=20s"

antiAffinity: "soft"

resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "1Gi"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "1Gi"

esJavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi

esConfig:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    xpack.security.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.client_authentication: required
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12


secretMounts:
  - name: elastic-certificates
    secretName: elastic-certificates
    path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
```

Values for kibana chart:

```
elasticSearchHosts: "https://elasticsearch-master:9200"

extraEnvs:
  - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elasticsearch-creds
        key: username
  - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elasticsearch-creds
        key: password
  - name: KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: encryption-key  
        key: encryption_key

kibanaConfig:
  kibana.yml: |
    server.ssl:
      enabled: true
      key: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/elastic-certificate.pem
      certificate: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/elastic-certificate.pem
    xpack.security.encryptionKey: ${KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    elasticsearch.ssl:
      certificateAuthorities: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/elastic-certificate.pem
      verificationMode: certificate
    
protocol: https

secretMounts:
  - name: elastic-certificate-pem
    secretName: elastic-certificate-pem
    path: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs

imageTag: "7.17.3"

ingress:
  enabled: true
  ingressClassName: nginx
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: 'false'
  paths:
    - path: /
      pathType: Prefix
      backend:
        serviceName: kibana
        servicePort: 5601
  hosts:
    - host: mydomain.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            serviceName: kibana
            servicePort: 5601
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mydomain.com
      secretName: mydomain.com
```

UPD: tried it with other image version (8.4.1), nothing has changed, i am getting the same error. By the way, logstash is successfully  shipping logs to this elasticsearch instance, so i think problem is in kibana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. It was a complete pain in the ass. I hope these tips will help others:

1. `xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled` should be set to false. I can't find another way around it, but if you do i'd be glad to hear any advices. As i see it, you don't need security for http layer since kibana connects to elastic via transport layer (correct me if i am wrong). Therefore `xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled` should be still set to true, but `xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled` should be set to false. (don't forget to change your `protocol` field for readinessProbe to http, and also change protocol for elasticsearch in kibana chart to http.
2. `ELASTIC_USERNAME` env variable is pointless in elasticsearch chart, only password is used, user is always `elastic`
3. `ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME` in kibana chart should be actually set to `kibana_systems` user with according password for that user

Comment: With version kibana.7.17 and onwards, xpack parameters are not valid, I added my solution in below

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the self signed CA for Elasticsearch to Kibana in kibana.yml

```
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: "/path/cert.ca"
```

You can test by setting

```
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: "none"
```

But that is not recommended for production.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i did provide cert; you can see it at `kibanaConfig:` in my values for kibana

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: just uncomment the elasticsearch.username and elasticsearch.password from **kibana.yml**.

**Step 2**: restart the elasticsearch.

**Step 3** : restart the kibana

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My elasticsearch api host was https on 9200
So I followed below steps to make kibana portal working

1. Resetted password for kibana, from elasticsearch installation directory

   .\elasticsearch-reset-password.bat -u kibana_system --auto
2. Uncommented below entries in kibana.yml. Added https for host, new password

   elasticsearch.hosts: "https://localhost:9200"
   elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
   elasticsearch.password: "<your_password_from_step1>"
3. set elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
4. Start kibana.bat from kibana folder install, wait for to say http server running on localhost:5601
5. Login with elastic username and password; yup elastic not kibana